# Using 'Auto-Sync' feature of DBML with SQLite

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, sqlite

I'm having trouble trying to use the 'Auto-Sync' feature of DBML with SQLite.  I have a class in my data model that contains a primary key (`id`).  This key is defined as "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY", which SQLite maps to the `rowid` of the row.  To support this, I have set "Auto Generated Value" to 'True' and "Auto-Sync" to 'OnInsert'.

The problem is, when I commit a new entry to the database, the `SELECT` string used by the LINQ to SQL classes is not supported by SQLite:

```
SELECT CONVERT(BigInt,SCOPE_IDENTITY()) AS [value]
```

Instead, SQLite has the `last_insert_rowid()` function, which I cannot seem to point to.

Does anyone know how to remedy this?  Possibly by changing the statement used to select the last row ID or some other trick I'm missing?

**EDIT** There appears to be [some](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/1846.aspx) [traffic](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/1670.aspx) on the provider's website, but no resolutions.

**EDIT** Since I seem to have confused the question, here's how I've set up my application.  Hopefully it helps shed some light on my thought process, and maybe an underlying issue.

- Add new "LINQ to SQL Classes" file to my solution
- Model my database in the designer, named `DataModel`
- Open a database using a `System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection`
- Initialize the `DataModel` instance using this connection

Comment: hmm.. DBML = Linq-to-SQL = SQL Server only. Not sure what you're trying to do here - but aren't DBML files part of Linq-to-SQL which is targeted at SQL Server as a backend only?

Comment: I should have mentioned...  I'm using System.Data.SQLite (http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) as the backend, which supports the ADO.NET Entity Framework.

Comment: Could you clarify whether you're using LINQ to SQL / DBML (which doesn't support SQLite) as per your question and tags, or the Entity Framework / EDMX (which does support SQLite, via the library you mention) as per your comment?

Comment: @itowlson: well, I suppose I'm not exactly sure.  I updated my question to show how I've set up the connection and used the DBML with it.  Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding a "Linq-to-SQL" data model to your project, but you're using it against SQLite - that'll never work of course! Linq-to-SQL **only** ever supports SQL Server (always has, always will), and thus its SQL statements that it generates are SQL Server T-SQL Statements - nothing else.

If you want to use the Entity Framework with SQLite, you need to use "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" (file with the .EDMX extension) as your data model.

[image]

Only that will support third-party database drivers like SQLite and others!

Comment: Thanks for the answer...  and bummer.  I didn't realize that LINQ to SQL was so tightly coupled to SQL server.  Unfortunately, I don't have an option to create the ADO.NET Entity Data Model (DevStudio Standard).  The LINQ to SQL works great for simple queries and inserts, but seems to fail for this case only, so far.

Answer (score 0):

Devart implementation of LINQ to SQLite does not contain this problem. The autoincrememnt column is treated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and found the following workaround - use the `SQLiteConnection.Changed` event to intercept the query and fix it up:

```
SQLiteConnection.Changed += (obj, eventArgs) => {
    var cmd = eventArgs.Command;
    if (eventArgs.EventType == SQLiteConnectionEventType.NewDataReader && cmd != null)
    {
        cmd.CommandText = cmd.CommandText.Replace( @"SELECT CONVERT(Int,SCOPE_IDENTITY()) AS [value]"
                                                    , @"; SELECT last_insert_rowid() AS value");
    }
};
```